# Is $C^1(\Omega) \subseteq H^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

My question is very simple, and this might be very trivial - but I appreciate the help.

Are the once continuously differentiable functions $C^1(\Omega)$ a subset of the Sobolev space $H^2(\Omega)$ containing functions with $L^2$-integrable weak derivatives up to and including order 2? In other words, does the inclusion
$$
C^1(\Omega) \subseteq H^2(\Omega)
$$
hold?

Comment: Is $C^0\subset H^1$? In that case the answer is affirmative. Look "Sobolev embeddings"

Comment: What's $\Omega$?

Comment: Hi @RiccardoCeccon, $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with Lipschitz-continuous boundary.

Comment: A trivial counterexample: $\Omega = (0,1)$, $f(x) = 1/x$.  Probably you mean under $C^1(\Omega)$ a space of functions that not only have continuous first derivatives on $\Omega$ but satisfy some other condition?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: aren't Sobolev embeddings only relevant for the reverse inclusion? Seems to me that $C^0 \subset H^1$ is never true for nontrivial domains.

Comment: @anthonycarapetis: In that case the answer to the OP is negative. I wasn't implying anything else than what I wrote :-)

Comment: Cool, just checking I wasn't missing something. The antiderivative of [Cantor's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a nice counterexample for $\Omega=[0,1],$ and should be easily adapted to arbitrary $\Omega$ using coordinates and a bump function.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: Please, can you post this as an answer? I tried posting a CW but some zealous guys deleted it. Thank you

Comment: @IvarStangeby: I think that you should **accept** Anthony's answer. Please click on the green check sign that appears just below the vote arrows. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Giuseppe pointed out in the comments, by passing to the derivative we can consider the simpler question $C^0 \overset ? \subset H^1$ instead, since for a $H^1$ function $f$ we have the equivalences $$f \in C^1 \iff \nabla f \in C^0$$ and $$f \in H^2 \iff \nabla f \in H^1.$$ Thus the central issue is comparing the strength of continuity to weak differentiability. It turns out that weak differentiability is (loosely) the stronger condition, so the inclusion you propose does not hold for any (non-trivial) domain.

In one dimension this is very clear-cut: weakly differentiable functions are all absolutely continuous, which is a strictly stronger condition than plain continuity. Thus when $\Omega \subset \mathbb R$ we can generate a counterexample by starting with a function which is continuous but not absolutely continuous, such as the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)  $c$. Since $c\in C^0$ but $c \notin H^1,$ the antiderivative $f(x) = \int_0^x c$ is $C^1$ but not $H^2$.

In general, you can always adapt this idea by taking a product and localizing, i.e. letting $f(x,y,\ldots,z) = \eta(x,y,\ldots,z)\int_0^x c$ where $\eta$ is some smooth bump function supported in $\Omega.$

Comment: Good answer. Thank you!